# Endeca- EQL negation query

Tags: endeca

I want to write a dimension value query to filter the records based on dimension values. I have a requirement to use the `"!="` operator in the `EQL query`. I know that `EQL queries` support this operator and it also given in the manual that even dimension value queries support this. In the manual examples are given only for property value queries. I tried to implement the same for dimension value queries but the application did not return any records for that. Can anyone help me with an example for dimension value queries for this operator?
below is the query I am trying, but it does not return any result as there is some problem with the query:

```
Nrs=collection()/record[GROUP=collection("dimensions")/dval[name="GROUP"]/dval[name!="G001"]]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Sav

Answer (score 1):

Put "not" in front of the whole expression.  Try:

```html
collection()/record[ not (  Genre = collection("dimensions")/dval[name="Genre"]//id ) ]
```

Note that there are some minor wrinkles.  For more info, check out page 105 in this document.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55324_01/Mdex.651/pdf/DevGuide.pdf